# How to create grid with sticky columns AND headers?

Tags: html, css

I have a spreadsheet-style grid. The root looks like this:

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="left-column"></div>
  <div id="center-column"></div>
  <div id="right-column"></div>
<div>
```

The left and right columns are each 1 column but the center column is `N` number of columns.

When scrolling left and right, I want to lock the left and right column in place so they are always visible. And only scroll-x the center columns.

However when scrolling vertically, I want to lock the first cell in all columns (the header cell) so they are always visible.

I have this almost working:

```js
// JS is only used to generate the cells

const cells = Array.from({ length: 20 }).map(c => c = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 50}px`)
cells[0] = '120px'
cells[19] = '120px'

const first = cells.shift()
const last = cells.pop()

const rows = Array.from({ length: 100 })

const grid = document.getElementById("grid")
const leftColumn = document.getElementById("left-column")
const centerColumn = document.getElementById("center-column")
const rightColumn = document.getElementById("right-column")

grid.style.display = "grid"
grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `${first} 1fr ${last}`

function makeItem(text) {
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.classList.add('cell')
  const newContent = document.createTextNode(text);
  div.appendChild(newContent);
  return div;
}

function makeRow() {  
  const innerGrid = document.createElement("div")
  innerGrid.style.display = "grid"
  innerGrid.style.gridTemplateColumns = cells.join(' ')
  
  cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
    const child = makeItem(`cell ${index + 1}`)
    innerGrid.appendChild(child)
  })
  
  const a = makeItem('First')
  const z = makeItem('Last')
  
  leftColumn.appendChild(a)
  centerColumn.appendChild(innerGrid)
  rightColumn.appendChild(z)
}

rows.forEach(() => {
  makeRow()
})
```

```css
.cell {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  color: #333;
  height: 30px;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#grid {
  width: min(100%, 1000px);
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
}
#center-column {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
#left-column > .cell, #right-column > .cell, #center-column > :first-child > .cell {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #eee;
}

#left-column > :first-child,
#right-column > :first-child,
#center-column > :first-child,
#center-column > :first-child > .cell{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #d70000;
}
#center-column {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="left-column"></div>
  <div id="center-column"></div>
  <div id="right-column"></div>
<div>
```

However when you scroll vertically, the left and right column headers stay locked but the center headers do not.

I know why. This is because in order to achieve the horizontal scrolling behavior I want, I need to make the center column have overflow scroll. This kills the position sticky that is making the headers lock in place (just for the center columns).

So I know the problem causing it not to work. But I cannot find a pure css work around. I can use JavaScript to make this work but I am trying to find a pure css solution.

I can use whatever nested html elements and styling are needed I just want a pure css solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create physical wrappers DIVs. Just create your cells, place them inside your #grid element and play with CSS and the `:nth-child()` pseudo class selector and make the desired cols, rows `sticky` at `top` `left` `right` respectively.

Here's an example of a 6 columns grid:

```js
// This JS is only used to dynamically generate the cells.

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const repeat = (n, cb) => [...Array(n)].forEach((_, i) => cb(i));

const elGrid = el("#grid");
repeat(90, (i) => {
   elGrid.append(elNew("div", {
     className: "cell",
     textContent: `Cell ${i+1}`
   }));
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

#grid {
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  
  .cell {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    min-width: 20vw;
    
    /* leftmost column */
    &:nth-child(6n-5) {
      background: #ddd;
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    /* rightmost column */
    &:nth-child(6n) {
      background: #ddd;
      position: sticky;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    /* top row */
    &:nth-child(-n+6) {
      background: #aaa;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    /* first cell */
    &:nth-child(1) {
      z-index: 2;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```